# all children selector in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

simplified, i've got following code:

```
 <a id="123" href="#"><span>click</span><span>me</span></a>
```

when i click on 'click' and 'me' it doesnt seem to work with following jquery selector:

```
 $("a").click...
```

maybe its because i click on the children? how could i write the selector so it maps to all children in 'a'?

Comment: The code you have there should work do you have a link to your page?

Comment: It should work. Can you post the code? http://jsbin.com/ekedo3

Comment: Indeed, it is working just fine!

Comment: ok i think i know what's the problem is. the 'a' got an id and with jquery i will show some content based on that id. but when i click on the children they DONT contain that id. its the parent 'a' that has got the id. so when i click on the children i have to fetch the parent's id. how could i do this? im currently using event.target.id on the children too but how do i rewrite this so if gets the id of the parent? (long comment=))

Comment: Post your code, the click event is firing as expected.

Comment: @noname, you are not reading the comments... there is nothing wrong with the code you have shown us ... the problem lies somewhere else.. the 'a' gets the click .. not the spans inside it..

Comment: @gaby. i typed alert(event.target.id) and then i clicked on the spans and they showed nothing. then i clicked on the 'a' (you have to move your mouse to the corners outside the spans) and it alerts me the nr of the ID. so that what the problem is. when i click on the spans it fires the span. look at my more detailed question.

Comment: @noname, if you use the `this` keyword you will get the element that has your function in (in your case the 'a'). so `alert( this.id )` will show '123'. Alternatively you can use `event.currentTarget.id` which again shows the actual element that captured the event..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[updated]***
The problem is that you are using the wrong tool for the job (namely the event.target property). This will return the element that the event happened **on**.. but not the element in the bubbling phase that handles the event... you need to use the `event.currentTarget`.. 
But in jQuery's case this is also the same as the `this` keyword inside the handler ...
ref: http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/

Have a read at the [Event order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) as explained at quirksmode. Special attention to *[Use of event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link6)* and *[currentTarget](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link10)*

---

***[previous answer]***
Make sure that inside the `.click` method you use a function pointer or an anonymous function ..

so

```
$("a").click( function() {/*...*/} ); // anonymous function
```

or

```
function some_function()
{
//...
}
$("a").click ( some_function ) // function pointer
```

but **not**

```
$("a").click ( some_function() ) // unless some_function returns a function pointer..
```

Comment: +1, although I don't think the term "function pointer" really applies in a language where functions are first-class citizens...

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get the id of a parent element then you just do this:

```
$('a').children().click(function() {
  var parentId = $(this).parent('a').attr('id');
  // Code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> i have to fetch the parent's id. how could i do this? im currently using event.target.id

`$(event.target).closest('a').attr('id')` would do it.

But there's no need to use `event.target`: in an event handler function the special `this` variable will point to the element you added the handler to, rather than the descendant element that was clicked:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    alert('id= '+this.id)
});
```

(Or `$(this).attr('id')` if you want to force jQuery to do some extraneous work.)

PS. Don't use IDs that start with a number. It's invalid and can confuse some browsers.